# nodejs mysql ReferenceError: post is not defined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm learning how to make rest requests, but got this problem

I have 3 routs

one for insert

```
    app.get("/addUser",(req, res)=>{
    let post = {usersName : "user3", userStarus:"1", GroupId : "3"};
    let sql = "insert into test.usersnames set ?";
    let query =  connection.query(sql, post, (err, result)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        res.send("post added");
    })
});
```

ans it works

but 2 others like delete and update doesn't work

```
app.get("/deleteUser/:id",(req, res)=>{
    let sql = `delete from test.usersnames  
                where usernames.id=${req.params.id}`;
    let query =  connection.query(sql, post, (err, result)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        res.send("post deleted");
    })
});
```

it returns an error

> ReferenceError: post is not defined

what's the difference? why can it insert but can't delete or update a record when i'm trying to pass record's id ?

Comment: You didn't define `post` in your `get` route

Comment: @JosanIracheta  I did it all by .get; should I redo it to be get, post, delete and put?

Answer (score 1):

In first example you are defining the variable post

```
let post = {usersName : "user3", userStarus:"1", GroupId : "3"};
```

but not in second one.

Comment: yea right, i didn't need this post parameter in delete

Answer (score 1):

When you define a variable with let or const. It's available only in his scope. So in  your second request, post isn't define

Comment: i don't think i even need it there; I did it all by .get; should I redo it to be get, post, delete and put?

Comment: if you don't need post for delete request , why did you put it on parameter of connection.query() ? You reference an variable which doesn't exist that why you get an error.

Answer (score 1):

In the second query you should use "[Escaping query value](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values)" something similar to prepared statement to avoid [sql injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection):

```
let sql = 'delete from test.usersnames  
            where usernames.id=?';

connection.query(sql, [ req.params.id ], (err, result) => { ... });
```